# I have a JSON file with 379000 lines and it is full with double quotes inside the string objects,how can I delete all of them?

Tags: json, double-quotes

The invalid format:
"studwhere": "Academia de Muzica "Gheorghe Dima" Cluj-Napoca",

Expected result:
"studwhere": "Academia de Muzica Gheorghe Dima Cluj-Napoca",
or
"studwhere": "Academia de Muzica \"Gheorghe Dima\" Cluj-Napoca",

Comment: If the file really contains those quotes, and you're not just getting confused by odd behavior in the debugger when inspecting variable contents, then that is simply not json. You will have to somehow parse the file to know whether a quote is correct or not. Is there no option to go back to the source and tell the producer of that file to fix their file format to be legal json?

Comment: As an example of what you might have to contend with: `"key": "Academia de Muzica", "Gheorghe Dima": "Test"` How do you know that that value doesn't just have an awful lot of extra quotes and colons and stuff? You might need to write a parser that sees both the invalid syntax, such as in your example, or identifies things that are values but looks like valid json. Or you can take an ostrich approach and hope this problem doesn't occur. It is rather contrived, I'll give you that.

Comment: I'd say open the file in your favorite text editor, and see if you can formulate a regular expression that identifies them, but not the legal ones, whereas "legal ones" might be quotes that aren't either followed by a colon, or preceeded by a colon and a space.

Comment: This *can* give you false positives and skip false negatives, you will have to make the best of the situation. Once you know more about what kinds of things you need to fix, you can codify that into a program.

Comment: You can use for example VS Code. It should handle very big files. And then you need Regex expression to replace what you want.